# Extremely noisy signal after voltage follower/buffer

Tags: voltage, noise, buffer, distortion

I am trying to create a voltage follower for my CCD linear array. When I measure the signal with oscilloscope directly from the CCD outptut - the signal is reasonably clean. However, when I measure if after the voltage follower, the signal is extremely noisy. Distorted?

The analog output from the CCD fluctuates between 5V and 8V. The readout rate is around 1MHz. Therefore, I am using AD8004 OpAmp 250MHz bandwidth, 3000V/us. I power it with -Vs=0V and +Vs=12V.

[image: Connection Schematic]

Putting a 10uF cap on the power line next to the IC does not help. Please, help to find the reason of such noisy output.

Comment: How about a schematic and some scope captures?

Comment: Also what kind of scope probe are you using? It's possible the scope probe capacitance is filtering out noise when you probe directly.

Comment: What is the output impedance of the CCD?

Comment: Can not get scope pictures now. The schematic is simple: Vin+ is connected to the CCD ouput, Vin- is connected to the Vout of the opAmp. I would say the signal is rather distorted. The manual says that the probe is passive.

Comment: @apalopohapa The specsheet does not say. Only says that the typical capacitance at the output pin is about 45pF. It also says that "_the half power bandwidth into an external load of 10pF is 150MHz_"

Comment: The input bias current seems a bit high on the AD8004 (up to 100uA) and it may or may not be loading the CCD.  Also, is the whole op amp quad being used, are you leaving any of them floating?  Additionally, 10uF is good for bulk, but you need high frequency bypassing.  Try a small 0.1uF as well.  Furthermore, it is a video op-amp, which usually has a 150 ohm load, so it is probably optimized for it, so try loading it with an output resistor as well.

Comment: @Naz, if you did not connect your op-amp to a power supply, that is probably part of your problem. If you did connect your op-amp to a power supply, then your text description of your circuit is incomplete, and I'd recommend you **add a schematic** so that what we can understand what circuit you're asking us about.

Comment: It will be helpful if your schematic includes any power supply connections, bypass capacitors, and loads on the output that are present in your circuit.

Comment: You can't run the AD2004 like a normal op-amp - it's a current feedback op-amp and, connecting its o/p to -Vin is wrong, very wrong I believe.

Comment: @Naz, I rolled back your recent edit, because it removed the information about which amp you used --- without which your accepted answer does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the datasheet, the AD8004 does not seem to be a great choice for a voltage follower, and some special consideration might be needed if you are going to use it that way.

- Nowhere in the datasheet is it claimed that the amplifier is gain-of-1 stable. However some specs are given for gain-of-+1 configurations, so it's not entirely impossible to use it this way.
- Where gain-of-+1 specs are given, a feedback resistance (R<sub>f</sub>) of 700 - 1100 ohms is specified. There are no specs for how the part will operate in the usual voltage-follower configuration with a short circuit (R<sub>f</sub> = 0 ohms) connection from output to inverting input.
- The frequency response in the G=+1 configuration shows substantial peaking.

My conclusion from this is that the amplifier is "just barely" stable in unity-gain configurations. Very possibly your amplifier is oscillating if you have hooked up the standard "voltage follower" configuration.

If you do want to use AD8004 as a follower, you should definitely include a resistor in the feedback path (806 or 1.21k ohms are recommended in table I of the data sheet).

As a comment suggested, you also must be sure to connect the pins of any unused amps in the package in such a way that they will maintain a steady voltage. If you leave them open, the unused outputs are likely to fluctuate randomly. And this fluctuation is likely to couple (for example, through the power supply) to the used amplifier and exacerbate any problem you have with stability.

But even safer, especially given you have only a 1 MHz input signal, would be to find a more appropriate op-amp for this application.

Comment: Definitely needs a feedback resistor for this device - -Vin is 50 ohms input resistance!!!

Comment: @The Photon: yes. after putting 820 ohm resistor in the feedback loop the problem disappeared. Thank you. Just wanted to ask about the unused pins. Would it be ok to ground them all? Also, I will try the suggested by Spehro Pefhany ADA4800. But in general, I was wrong with choosing this component as a buffer. So, which specs I should be focusing on when looking for an appropriate buffer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to look for a device that has "unity gain stable" in its description, and you need a gain-bandwidht product above 1 MHz. 2-5 MHz would be fine. 250 MHz is massive overkill. After that you'll narrow down your selection based specs like offset voltage or load-driving capability or price, depending on requirements that aren't part of this question.

Comment: As for the unused pins, definitely **don't** ground the output pins. With normal (voltage feedback) op-amps, I usually configure unused devices on a chip as voltage followers and tie the + input to a mid-level voltage. I dunno if that's best for the AD8004 though.

Comment: @ThePhoton: My previous experience showed that even 16MHz bandwidth was not sufficient. I used MC33078, however, it was altering the shape of the signal - square components were becoming triangular.

Comment: Okay, then I misinterpreted what you wrote in the question. When you say the signal is "1 MHz" I thought you were talking about the full bandwidth. From your comment it sounds like you meant something else.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the CCD output can be an open-source transistor, so you need some kind of load to ground. Also, the amplifier you've chosen is a current feedback type.

You might want to consider the [ADA4800](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADA4800.pdf), which incorporates a programmable active load. 
Surprisingly inexpensive ($1.59 in one-off from Digikey).

Comment: I finally received the ADA4800. Was very excited to try it out. But... they were 1.6mmx1.6mmx0.55mm in size!))) Too bad I did not pay attention at the datasheet... and there are no other packages.

Comment: It's a bummer, but 0.5mm pitch should be do-able with fine wires, fine solder, a fine tip, and a decent microscope. I do it from time to time.